# Laravel Inserting multiple records, with non array variable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Hi I have a table (project) that can have multiple users assigned to it. When creating a new project i need to insert the selected users into a link table with the user's id and the created project_id.

```
    $project = new Project;
    $project->project_name = $request->project_name;
    $project->expected_start_date = $request->expected_start_date;
    $project->expected_end_date = $request->expected_end_date;
    $project->project_desc = $request->project_desc;
    $project->client_id = $request->client_id;
    $project->save();

    foreach($request->user_id as $user){
        $link_project_user = new link_project_user;
        $link_project_user->user_id = $user;
        $link_project_user->project_id = $project->id;
        $link_project_user->save();
    }
```

At the moment I am creating the project and getting the id via $project->id, then looping through the selected user's and creating a new user for each one.

However this seems slightly inefficient as this would in theory make multiple queries to the database. What would be the most effective and optimal way of implementing the above inserts.

I had originally tried passing in an array of users, however this then required an array of project id's.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a mass insert, like this.

```
$project = new Project;
$project->project_name = $request->project_name;
$project->expected_start_date = $request->expected_start_date;
$project->expected_end_date = $request->expected_end_date;
$project->project_desc = $request->project_desc;
$project->client_id = $request->client_id;
$project->save();

$lpus = [];

foreach($request->user_id as $user){
    $link_project_user["user_id"] = $user;
    $link_project_user["project_id"] = $project->id;
    $lpus[] = $link_project_user;   
}

link_project_user::insert($lpus);
```

Comment: Simple elegant solution, thank you very much! I had thought of this but i thought there was potentially a built in Laravel feature.